# Contract refund gets "Error: invalid address"

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging

Here is a contract I deployed on my private network:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract test {
    string stat;
    address owner;

    event statChanged(string _stat);

    function test() {
        stat = "INIT";
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() payable {
        stat = "PAID";
    }

    function getStat() constant returns (string) {
        return stat;
    }

    function getBalance() constant returns (uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }

    function getOwner() constant returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function send2Owner() {
        owner.transfer(this.balance);
    }

    function update(string _stat) {
        stat = _stat;
        statChanged(_stat);
    }
}
```

I send ETH to the contract:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: owner, to: contract, value: 1100000, gas: 200000, gasPrice: 1})
```

By running the contract .getBalance() I can see that the correct amount of ETH has arrived at the contract address, .getOwner() I can also see a good owner address too. Finally, I run .send2Owner to send the ETH back to owner:

```
var testContract = web3.eth.contract(...).at("...");
testContract.send2Owner();
```

Now I get this error:

```
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3879:15
    at web3.js:3705:20
    at web3.js:4948:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4947:12
    at web3.js:4973:18
    at web3.js:4998:23
    at web3.js:4061:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4147:16
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: where  you define the web3 var?

Comment: To answer your question, I run the script in geth console by loadScript("send2Owner.js"). In the script contains something like the following before getting the error -->
var testContract = web3.eth.contract(...).at("...");
var output = testContract.send2Owner();
console.log(output);

Comment: First check if the abi and the contract adress are the real adress before this `web3.eth.contract(...).at("...");`, i don't know how work in geth but for example if you use metamask you need a web3 injected item for the good conection with the account, so you problem is when you try to send cause this is diferent action  , you can check balance and getOwner because this don't do any change in the blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed a parameter when I launch .send2Owner()

```
var testContract = web3.eth.contract(...).at("...");
testContract.send2Owner();
```

This is the correct version

```
var testContract = web3.eth.contract(...).at("...");
testContract.send2Owner({from:eth.accounts[0]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the default account and then execute:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

Hope this helps...!